# Eclipse/Java can't start any project

Tags: java, eclipse, classloader, launcher

I was working on my Java Code without problems. Then I updated to Java 8 because of that I could not start Eclipse anymore. So I downgraded it again to Java 7. Now I can start Eclipse but if I try to start any Java project I get this:

> Thread [main] (Ausgesetzt (Ausnahmebedingung UnsupportedClassVersionError))
>   Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line:not available
>   Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(String,boolean) line: not available
>   Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: not available
>   LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(boolean, int, String) line: not available
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe(10.06.2015 19:24:48)

Already searched on google for this problem. There were some solutions with Step-filtering but it does not help.
Hope someone could help me. (If there are some words you don't understand: thats german but don't worry they are not necessary)
Thanks

Comment: Sometimes it's just faster to download fresh Eclipse then trying to fix a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly specify the -vm argument in eclipse.ini file as in below and restart eclipse

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

If you still face the issue, try to open eclipse in new workspace and import your projects which are in old workspace folder into new workspace folder

Note: It is advisable to have jdk as value for -vm argument rather than jre

Answer (score 1):

Update your java path to point to Java 7.